# How to calculate the minimum distance of a cyclic code

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

Let $C$ be the cyclic code of length $63$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ that has generator polynomial $$g(x)=(x+1)(x^6+x+1)(x^6+x^5+1)$$

We are asked to comment on the minimum distance of $C$. However I don't understand how to find the minimum distance. Can anyone explain how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be a good idea to list a few items you have covered in class. This question is a bit on the thin side in terms of such context. The thought you want to dispel is that you are trying to simply out source your homework :-)

Comment: In general, it's not trivial to compute the minimum distance of a cyclic code given $g(x)$. What is relatively trivial is: $d_{min} \le w(g(x))$ where $w(g(x))$ is the weight of the generating polynomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always first check what the BCH-bound gives you.

It is known (and easy to check) that the irreducible polynomial $p(x)=x^6+x+1$ is primitive. In other words $n=63$ is the smallest integer such that $p(x)\mid x^n-1$. If $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_{64}$ is a zero of $p(x)$ then by Galois theory of finite fields so is $\alpha^2$. Of course, $\alpha^0$ is a zero of the factor $x+1$.

IMO the key to this exercise is that the third factor is the reciprocal polynomial of $p(x)$, that is
$$
\tilde{p}(x)=x^6+x^5+1=x^6p(\frac1x).
$$
From this we see immediately $\alpha^{-1}$ and $\alpha^{-2}$ are zeros of the factor $\tilde{p}(x)$.

So we have shown that $\alpha^j$ is a zero of the generator polynomial polynomial for five consecutive values of $j=-2,-1,0,1,2$. The BCH-bound then tells us that the minimum distance of the code is at least $5+1=6$. I leave it to you to verify that the generator polynomial is itself of weight six. We can thus conclude that the minimum distance of this code is $d_{min}=6$.

---

It may be worth observing that because $x+1$ is a factor of the generator, all the codewords have $x=1$ as a zero. Therefore they must have an even weight.

Comment: Sometimes the Hartmann-Tzeng bound gives a stronger result than the BCH-bound. For example, if we drop the factor $(x+1)$ from the generator, the BCH-bound will fall flat on its face. But there are two strings of zeros of $p(x)\tilde{p}(x)$, namely $\alpha^{-4+3j}$, $j=0,1,2$ and $\alpha^{-1+3j}$, $j=0,1,2$, and Hartmann-Tzeng shows that the resulting code has minimum distance $\ge3+1+1=5$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and concise explanation. This has helped me a lot. Also thanks for the tip. I will keep that in mind for next time and make sure I add a bit more detail to my questions :-)

Comment: @math189925 shouldn't you accept this answer?